# What is the difference between conda-forge and cf-staging channels

Tags: conda, conda-build, conda-forge

I have a package that I maintain in [**PyPi**](https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/) that I also placed on [**conda-forge**](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mplfinance) for those who prefer to install with `conda` rather than `pip`.

In the past, when I would update the version and SHA in the [**feedstock**](https://github.com/conda-forge/mplfinance-feedstock) it would automatically feed the new version into [**the conda-forge channel**](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mplfinance).  However my most recent update appears to have been propagated into a channel called [**cf-staging**](https://anaconda.org/cf-staging/mplfinance).

I am trying to figure out why it propagated into `cf-staging` instead of `conda-forge` and what I have to do to get it to move from `cf-staging` to conda-forge.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of the pipeline. It should eventually transfer, but if it goes more than a day, contact the admins or hop on [the Gitter chat](https://gitter.im/conda-forge/conda-forge.github.io).

As explained in [the documentation](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/infrastructure.html#output-validation-and-feedstock-tokens), Anaconda Cloud only allows one API token per channel, so in order to prevent maintainers of one feedstock from pushing builds of other packages, the Conda Forge team uses an intermediate channel (`cf-staging`) from where the CI tooling will run validation on submitted packages before sending them off to the `conda-forge` channel proper.

Among other things, this strategy helps mitigate against malicious users who might gain feedstock maintenance rights on an inconspicuous package, from later on rebuilding a popular package (like `python` or `numpy`) to include some malicious code and trying to push it from their feedstock onto the Conda Forge channel where it might deploy to tens of thousands of users.